# How can I increase SSL performance with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: performance, ssl, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I really like Elastic Beanstalk and managed to get my webapp (Spring MVC, Hibernate, ...) up and running using SSL on a Tomcat7 64-bit container.

A major concern to me is performance (I thought using the Amazon cloud would help here).

To benchmark my server performance I am using blitz.io (which uses the amazon cloud to have multiple clients access my webservice simultaneously).

My very first simple performance test already got me wondering:
I benchmarked a health check url (which basically just prints "I'm ok").

Without SSL: Looks fine.
13 Hits/s with a response time of 9ms
230 Hits/s with a response time of 8ms

With SSL: Not so fine.
13 Hits/s with a response time of 44ms (Ok, this should be a bit larger due to encryption overhead)
30 Hits/s with a response time of 3.6s!

Going higher left me with connection timeouts (timeout = 10s).

I tried using a larger EC2 instance in the background with essentially the same result.

If I am not mistaken, the Load Balancer before the EC2 Instances serves as an endpoint for SSL encryption. How do I increase this performance?

Can this be done with elastic beanstalk? Or do I need to setup my own load balancer etc.?

I also did some tests using Heroku (albeith with a slightly different technology stack, play! vs. SpringMVC). Here I also saw the increased response time, but it stayed mostly constant. I am assuming they are using quite performant SSL endpoints. How do I get that for Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems my testing method was flawed.

Amazon's Elastic Load Balancers seem to go up to 10k SSL requests per second.

See this great writeup:
http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/24620577877/part-2-how-elastic-are-amazon-elastic-load-balancers

Answer (score 1):

SSL requires a handshaking before a secure transmission channel is opened. Once the handshaking is done, which involves several roundtrips, the data is transmitted.

When you are just hitting a page using a load tester, it is doing the handshake for each and every hit. It is not reusing an already established session.

That's not how browsers are going to do. Browse will do handshake once and then reuse the open encrypted session for all the subsequent requests for a certain duration.

So, I would not be very worried about the results. I suggest you try a tool like www.browsermob.com to see how long a full page with many image, js, css etc takes to load over SSL vs non-SSL. That will be a fair comparison.

Helps?

Comment: This is not concerning a webpage, but a webservice which essentially handles the uploading of images. So it is important to handle many simultaneous requests, which each do a handshake.